# How do I bind value of a field component based on some calculations involving current field using <Input, onchange, oninput etc

Tags: blazor

CashDebtors percentage = 100 - (debtors60%  + debtors90% + debtors120% + debtors120plus%)

So each time I input value of debtors, I want to calculate remaining value for cash debtors. I tried this but its not working

```
<label for="DebtorsP30" class=">Debtors(%) 0-30</label>
  <div>
    <InputNumber class="form-control" @bind-Value=CashDebtorsPercent />
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="DebtorsP60">Debtors(%) 30-60</label>
  <div>
    <InputNumber @bind-Value=DebtorsPercent60 @oninput="@(e=>GetPercentage(1))" />
  </div>
</div>                            
<div>
  <label for="DebtorsP90">Debtors(%) 60-90</label>
  <div>
    <InputNumber @bind-Value=DebtorsPercent90 @oninput="@(e=>GetPercentage(1))" />
  </div>
</div>

@code
{
private decimal CashDebtorsPercent,DebtorsPercent60, DebtorsPercent90,                              DebtorsPercent120, DebtorsPercent130;

 //1 = Debtors; 2 = Creditors
 private async Task GetPercentage(int EntryType) 
 {
    if (EntryType == 1)
    {
       CashDebtorsPercent = 100 - (DebtorsPercent60 + DebtorsPercent90 +
                              DebtorsPercent120 + DebtorsPercent130);
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful if you would edit your code better.  Perhaps even remove the Tailwind classes, so it reads easier in these tiny windows they give us :)

If you edit it, and perhaps put a full sample, I might be able to offer more insight.  The code and markup don't quite match

Comment: Oh thanks Kevin, let me try below:

Comment: What isn't working? Give us some details on what is going wrong. Your code is hard to reproduce correctly as it is incomplete and what you are doing doesn't make much sense to me from to the tiny introduction you made.

Comment: Sorry @ZabronMuyambo, your code still does not entirely make sense. You've got some variables used in your code which are not defined.  Where are they coming from?  DebtorsPercent120, DebtorsPercent130, CashCreditorsPercent, etc...  where are these defined, what are their values?  Try this: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/3u0nbzbp and see if you can edit it to make it compile and run

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine The procedure to recalculate CashDebtors is not being called

Comment: Yes it is being called (probably), but for some reason, you made it `async Task`. However, you are calling it without `await`. Which means Blazor never knows when to rerender because it does not know when the method finishes executing.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I managed to get a working solution, even though I am not confident it may apply in all situations:

I converted my  lines to:

<input class="form-control" id="CreditorsP90" placeholder="00.00" type="number" step="any" @bind-Value:event="oninput" @bind-Value="@CreditorsPercent60"  @onchange=@(e => GetPercentage(1)) />

Thanks @T.Trassoudaine and @Kevon